# spring-boot application shutdown immediately after starting (schedular)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am going through the spring scheduler guide (https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) but my spring-boot application is terminating immediately after starting. I have checked all dependency and they seems to be fine. My output is

```
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:60501,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\my-data\code\spring-guides\spring-schedular\target\classes;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.9.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.13.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\ashis\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\ashis\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\172.3544.35\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.ashish.springschedular.SpringSchedularApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60501', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2017-12-18 06:24:30.882  INFO 11836 --- [           main] c.a.s.SpringSchedularApplication         : Starting SpringSchedularApplication on DESKTOP-SP4170I with PID 11836 (C:\my-data\code\spring-guides\spring-schedular\target\classes started by ashish in C:\my-data\code\spring-guides\spring-schedular)
2017-12-18 06:24:30.882  INFO 11836 --- [           main] c.a.s.SpringSchedularApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-18 06:24:31.053  INFO 11836 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1d8bd0de: startup date [Mon Dec 18 06:24:31 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-18 06:24:33.115  INFO 11836 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60501', transport: 'socket'
2017-12-18 06:24:33.161  INFO 11836 --- [           main] c.a.s.SpringSchedularApplication         : Started SpringSchedularApplication in 2.997 seconds (JVM running for 4.005)
2017-12-18 06:24:33.161  INFO 11836 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1d8bd0de: startup date [Mon Dec 18 06:24:31 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-18 06:24:33.161  INFO 11836 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My main application code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSchedularApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSchedularApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ashish</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-schedular</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-schedular</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

any my scheduler file:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static java.text.DateFormat.LONG;
import static java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance;
import static java.util.Locale.US;

@Component
public class ScheduledTask {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTask.class);
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance(LONG, US);

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void readCurrentTime(){
        log.info("The time is now[]", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `@EnableScheduling` to your application class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you so much. It worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Spring Boot enables a lot of things depending on your dependencies it doesn't do so for scheduling and async. You still need to manually enable that by adding, respectively, `@EnableScheduling` and `@EnableAsync`.

In your case adding `@EnableScheduling` to your application class is enough.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringSchedularApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSchedularApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

With this scheduling will be enabled and because there is a scheduling thread still running the application won't shutdown.